# A question about ticks on a graph

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-graphs

I am trying to make a graph with a grid in the background. I want it to be standard windows size, but I only want numbers next to the -10 and 10 on both the `x` axis and `y` axis. I am using this code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  xtick={-10,...,10},
  ytick={-10,...,10},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[domain=-3:3,blue,thick,samples=100,<->] {x^2};
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)(4,4)(6,-5)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(4,16)(6,6)(10,-5)};
%%\addlegendentry{$y=x^2$}
%%\addplot[domain=0:4,blue,] {x*x};
\addplot[domain=4:6,blue,] {x};
\addplot[domain=6:10,blue] {-5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I change `xtick={-10,...,10},` the grid also goes away and all the other ticks that are not `-10` or `10`

How can I make it so that the ticks are there but the numbers are not?

Updated: This is the updated version that fixed the original problem, but now I am trying to figure out a good placement for the x-axis, y-axis lables

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  xlabel style ={at={(1,0.5)},above right},
  ylabel style ={at={(0.5,1)},above right},
  xtick={-10,...,10},
  xticklabels={},    %% no x tick labels
  ytick={-10,...,10},
  yticklabels={},    %% no y tick labels
  extra x ticks={-10,10},
  extra x tick labels={-10,10},
  extra y ticks={-10,10},
  extra y tick labels={-10,10},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,blue,thick,samples=1000,->] {sqrt (x+4)};
%%\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)(4,4)(6,-5)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,2)(5,3)};
%%\addlegendentry{$y=x^2$}
%%\addplot[domain=0:4,blue,] {x*x};
%%\addplot[domain=4:6,blue,] {x};
%%\addplot[domain=6:10,blue] {-5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can set `xtick={-10,10},
  ytick={-10,10},
  minor tick num=19, grid=both`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
  xticklabels={},      %% no x tick labels
  yticklabels={},      %% no y tick labels
  extra x ticks={-10,10},
  extra x tick labels={-10,10},
  extra y ticks={-10,10},
  extra y tick labels={-10,10},
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  xtick={-10,...,10},
  xticklabels={},    %% no x tick labels
  ytick={-10,...,10},
  yticklabels={},    %% no y tick labels
  extra x ticks={-10,10},
  extra x tick labels={-10,10},
  extra y ticks={-10,10},
  extra y tick labels={-10,10},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[domain=-3:3,blue,thick,samples=100,<->] {x^2};
\addplot coordinates{(0,0)(4,4)(6,-5)};
\addplot coordinates{(4,16)(6,6)(10,-5)};
%%\addlegendentry{$y=x^2$}
%%\addplot[domain=0:4,blue,] {x*x};
\addplot[domain=4:6,blue,] {x};
\addplot[domain=6:10,blue] {-5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
xlabel style ={at={(1,0.5)},above right},
ylabel style ={at={(0.5,1)},above right},
```

in the axis options to get

[image]

For the edited question, you have to specify `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

```
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  xlabel style ={at={(1,0.5)},above right},
  ylabel style ={at={(0.5,1)},above right},
```

Complete code to remove confusion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-10,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  xlabel style ={at={(1,0.5)},above right},
  ylabel style ={at={(0.5,1)},above right},
  xtick={-10,...,10},
  xticklabels={},    %% no x tick labels
  ytick={-10,...,10},
  yticklabels={},    %% no y tick labels
  extra x ticks={-10,10},
  extra x tick labels={-10,10},
  extra y ticks={-10,10},
  extra y tick labels={-10,10},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10},clip=false
]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,blue,thick,samples=1000,->] {sqrt (x+4)};
%%\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)(4,4)(6,-5)};
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(5,3)};
%%\addlegendentry{$y=x^2$}
%%\addplot[domain=0:4,blue,] {x*x};
%%\addplot[domain=4:6,blue,] {x};
%%\addplot[domain=6:10,blue] {-5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great that was perfect. One more question, how can I get the x and y labels  to be a little more over to the right and a little more up respectively?

Comment: Now I cant see them, do I need to make something wider?

Comment: I can't see the little x and y label on the axis.

I am sorry, where do I put that?

I tried 

`grid=major,
  clip=false,
  xmin=-10,`

Comment: GREAT! 

Sorry  I thought I was supposed to replace them. I am new to this :)

I have one more question, and if you are getting sick of me I understand. How could I put an A above my point (0,2) and a B above my point (5,3)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23001/discussion-between-zzr0ck3r-and-harish-kumar).

Comment: Did you see my last reply in pm? It is putting the A on the bottom left

Comment: @zzr0ck3r I left a reply. :-)